# Remove characters after whitespace from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some date strings like so: 1/1/2010 10:34:11 PM, but I just want the MM/DD/YYYY format.

I have tried getting the segment of the string before " " by using something like this:

```
NSRange range = [dates[i] rangeOfString:@" "];

NSString *newString = [dates[i] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,range.location)];
```

However, it is not working correctly with the space as rangeOfString. How can I go about getting this to work correctly? Thanks!

Comment: use a date formatter to create a date from that string. use another to create a string in the fired format form the date.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It should work fine. You don't explain what's wrong with the result you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *dateString = @"1/1/2010 10:34:11 PM";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *newDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

// Output: 1/1/2010   
NSLog(@"new date string is %@", newDateString);
```

Comment: This is massive overkill when all the OP wants is a simple substring.

Answer (score 2):

do not do it like this.

Just use NSDateFormatter.
Convert from NSString to NSDate -> change fromat -> convert to string.

Answer (score 1):

Try [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) class to work with date formats.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use `NSDateFormatter`, a quick and dirty approach similar to what you tried would be using [`[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:):

```
NSArray *dateParts = [dates[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@", dateParts[0]);
```

Comment: Using `componentsSeparatedByString` is overkill when you only want the first value. Simply get the range of the first delimiter and then get the substring. Much more efficient.

Comment: Maybe, but on the other hand, it is one line.

Comment: It's actually two as written. Of course it can be one line, just like the OP's code can be one line. That's not the point. Your answer ends up scanning the entire string for the delimiter and then creates an array with all of the substrings. And all you need is the first. It's vastly more efficient to get the range of just the first delimiter (not all), and extract a single substring. No array needed, no need to scan the entire string, no need for lots of wasted substrings.

Comment: I understand your point, especially for much larger strings. But in this case (three substrings), you're pointing out a micro-optimization. I have disclaimed this answer as *quick and dirty* and provided it as a less lines of code alternative.